# Can't install dotnet 3.5 on windows 8.1 error code 0x800F0906

Tags: .net, windows

The dotnet3.5 installer (which uses windows update to install) fails silently after the progress bar shows. Installation fails repeated with every installation method.

---

(I'm posting this from memory, I was able to solve this issue)

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall updates KB2966826 and KB2966828
2. Install .net 3.5
3. Reinstall updates KB2966826 and KB2966828 from windows update.

Copy of the original post I found on tomshardware.com:

> A simple solution for many is to go to control panel / uninstall a program / view installed updates (top left corner) and then delete these two updates: KB2966826 and KB2966828. Then go back to windows update / view installed updates / enable windows features and check the .net framework 3.5. Then windows update will download it without saying it cannot connect to the internet. Windows update will reinstall the two removed updates later without any ill effect.

[Source (tomshardware.com)](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1893881/install-net-framework-windows.html)